# SharePoint setup where admin has no access to data

Tags: sharepoint-server, security, user, access, security-trimming

We have a customer who want's to store sensitive data on SharePoint which should only be accessed from a few members of the company. This would be no problem with SharePoint group policies, but we have two additional requirements:

The administrator should not have access to the data stored in the System. Even if he makes a complete backup and restore on another system he should have no access. Additionally all data should be encrypted without loss of functions in SharePoint (eg the fulltext search).

Is there a way to do this with native SharePoint Features? Or are there any third-party Tools which can be used to meet this requirements?